# Find the number of orders of every year

Tags: sql-server

I am new with SQL and I would like some help.

I am using MSSQL (Northwind database).

How is it possible to get all the orders of each year?

I know how to get every year from the order dates, but I have no idea how to approach on getting the total number of orders per year:

```
SELECT datepart(year,o.OrderDate)
FROM Orders o
   JOIN [Order Details] od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
   group by datepart(year,o.OrderDate)
```

Can anyone tell me where to look or provide some help?

There are a total of three years that come out as a result(1999,1998,1997)

There is a total of 830 orders in the database.

Doing a count(*) produces (691,405,1059) which is way off.

The tables:

[image: Tables]

Edit: The reason I am using join is because I will need the combined price of all orders per year as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Just add `count(*)`?

Comment: you don't need to `join` with `OrderDetails`, just do a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders WHERE DATEPART(year,orderdate) = 2017`

Comment: I am getting too many orders with count(*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : Use count Distinct for avoiding duplicate Order ID's

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT o.OrderID),YEAR(o.OrderDate)
FROM Orders o
JOIN [Order Details] od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID 
GROUP BY YEAR(o.OrderDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do a `Count(*)` and your group by is fine as it is.

```
SELECT datepart(year,o.OrderDate)
      , COUNT(*) TotalOrders
FROM Orders o
   JOIN [Order Details] od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
   group by datepart(year,o.OrderDate)
```

You can also write the same query as:

```
SELECT year(o.OrderDate) [Year]
      , COUNT(*) TotalOrders
FROM Orders o
   JOIN [Order Details] od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
   group by year(o.OrderDate)
```

Just a different `Datetime` function but does the same thing.

**EDIt**

If you just want to know the `Orders` per Year , you do not need to join it to the `Order Details` table , simply do the following :

```
SELECT year(o.OrderDate) [Year]
      , COUNT(*) TotalOrders
FROM Orders o
group by year(o.OrderDate)
```

Comment: @master2080 Have a look at the answer now, you do not need to join to the `Order Details`Table. simply run the query only against the `Orders` table.

Comment: Edited the main post explaining why I do need it.